# Filter dates from different spreadsheets for the last 10 days in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a sheet with 4 tabs with several data, where the date and time of the registration of the reports is in the column A. I created a new tab which will gather all the other sheets data. So I am using QUERY:

```
=QUERY({
Sheet2!A1:D;
Sheet3!A1:D;
Sheet4!A1:D;
Sheet5!A1:D
},
"select * where Col2 is not null order by Col1",0)
```

However, I need to place in Sheet1 all the data sorted by the last 10 days:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mzFEEZwDma0MAUUBnlmXvwWjCBpeDiaBDDXB584fu7A/edit#gid=0

Note: Query is already sorting by dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try ascending:

```
=SORT(QUERY(SORT({
 Sheet2!A1:D;
 Sheet3!A1:D;
 Sheet4!A1:D;
 Sheet5!A1:D}, 1, 0),
 "where Col2 is not null limit 10", 0))
```

or descending:

```
=QUERY(SORT({
 Sheet2!A1:D;
 Sheet3!A1:D;
 Sheet4!A1:D;
 Sheet5!A1:D}, 1, 0),
 "where Col2 is not null limit 10", 0)
```

Comment: Awesome. One little extra: is that possible to sort ascending or descending?